# MySQL: Display multiple results as a new row?

Tags: mysql

Ok, I have to admit I am not a genius with MySQL/phpMyAdmin but I'm always willing to learn. Theres currently a problem which I can't solve - spend the last few hours with Google and decided to ask here. This is what I've got:

```
SELECT products.products_id AS ID, media.file AS Image 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN media_link ON media_link.link_id = products.products_id 
JOIN media ON media.id = media_link.m_id 
ORDER BY ID;
```

and it works, basically. It looks like this:

```
ID | Image
1  | image.jpg
2  | image.jpg
2  | image2.jpg
3  | image.jpg
```

Is there a way to display it like this?

```
ID | Image     | Image2
1  | image.jpg |
2  | image.jpg | image2.jpg
3  | image.jpg |
```

I'm really not an expert, but is it even possible? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Generally, issues of data display are best handled in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: Yes and I guess thats the main issue here. The result of the query should be exported later when everything is done as an .csv file. So basically it needs to be done in phpMyadmin - as long if its possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will not be a good idea if you have unknown number of images for a single product.

I would suggest you to use `GROUP_CONCAT` instead:

```
SELECT products.products_id AS ID, GROUP_CONCAT(media.file) AS Image 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN media_link ON media_link.link_id = products.products_id 
JOIN media ON media.id = media_link.m_id 
GROUP BY products.product_id
ORDER BY products.product_id;
```

The result will be like:

```
ID  Image     
1   image.jpg 
2   image.jpg,image2.jpg
3   image.jpg
```

Comment: That looks promising, cheers for the quick response. Would it be possible to 'define' lets say 10 rows of additional image rows e.g. image1, image2... image10 and just leave empty fields as NULL? There are no more than I guess 6-7 additional images for each product. I wanted to do it that way in the beginning but I figured out that the system where the csv will be imported later can't handle images that are seperated by "," (so they have to be in their own row).

Comment: @Fannana: You can get the result you are looking for using row number. But, you have to be sure about the number of Images that may occur for 1 product.

Comment: Well thats the problem. The amount of images are different for each product. I also read something about temporary rows - not sure if would be workaround for this?

Comment: @Fannana: Then, I think you will have to use this method.

Comment: Alright. At least something I can work with for the moment. Thank you!